# Openshift - expose the containerPort as an environment variable

Tags: openshift, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka streams interactive query application. I created an RPC layer for the application instances to communicate. On Openshift, I have the following in my deployment config to get the actual pod ip which I then set as the application.server parameter.

```
 - name: MY_IP
   valueFrom:
   fieldRef:
   fieldPath: status.podIP
```

This sets an environment variable MY_IP to the actual IP. I would like to do the same for the port. However, I can't find any documentation on how to set an environment variable to the containerPort. I tried all kinds of variations of:

```
     valueFrom: 
     fieldRef:
     fieldPath: status.podPort
```

Nothing works.

This will work

```
   - name: MY_PORT
     value: '8080'
```

but it means that I have to hardcode the port number in 2 places in my deployment config. It would be better if I could pick up the port from

```
   ports:
   - containerPort: 8081
```

Is this supported? Is there another alternative to get the port?

Comment: If it's exposed as a service, the environment variable you need might already exist: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/environment_variables.html

Comment: That worked, I can use the <SVCNAME>_SERVICE_PORT automatically added environment variable

Answer (score 0):

The service port is exposed as an automatically added environment (see comment on the question) variable so that can be used to set the port number in the application.server parameter